# MySQL Statement Returns the same row twice

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement with multi joins as following :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   supplements 
       LEFT JOIN tutorials 
              ON supplements.id = tutorials.supplement_id 
       LEFT JOIN brands 
              ON supplements.brand_id = brands.id 
WHERE  supplements.id = '75'
```

When I run it , it return the row with the id 75 twice !

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Could you paste the structura and example data of your tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because your child table `tutorials` or `brands` might have got multiple values for `supplements.id` = 75

Comment: Oh thats True  , the table tutorials had multiple values for the same id , thank you a lot